# Changing from .group() to Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm doing this query in MongoDB. But I want this query iusing aggregation and not group. This is the query that I am using:

```
var query_part = {
    "shipdate" : { "$gte" : 19940101, "$lt" : 19950101 },
    "partsupp.supplier.nation.name" : { $regex : '^CANADA'}, 
    "partsupp.part.name" : { $regex : '^forest', $options : 'i' }
};

var red = function(doc, out) {
    out.sum += doc.quantity;
};

var half_total_quantity = db.lineitems.group( {
    key : "sum_quantity",
    cond : query_part,
    initial : { sum : 0 },
    reduce : red
})[0].sum / 2;
```

I'm trying to change the half_total_quantity calculation like this:

```
db.lineitems.aggregate(
{ $match : {$and : [{"shipdate" : { "$gte" : 19940101, "$lt" : 19950101 }},
                    {"partsupp.supplier.nation.name" : { $regex : '^CANADA'}},
                    {"partsupp.part.name" : { $regex : '^forest', $options : 'i' }}
                    ]}},
{ $group : { 
    sum_quantity : { $sum: "$quantity" }
}}
);
```

But this not works, can someone help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost never need `$and` since **all** MongoDB query operations are already "AND" conditions unless explicitly stated otherwise.

Also [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) requires and `_id`, which would be `null` here to indicate grouping "everything":

```js
db.lineitems.aggregate([
    { "$match": { 
        "shipdate" : { "$gte" : 19940101, "$lt" : 19950101 },
        "partsupp.supplier.nation.name" : { "$regex": '^CANADA' },
        "partsupp.part.name" : { "$regex": '^forest', "$options": 'i' }
    }},
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": null,
        "sum_quantity": { "$sum": "$quantity" }
    }}
]);
```

Not to forget the brackets `[]` since this is a "list" of pipeline expressions, afterall.

And to add the "halfTotalQuantity" thing, just [`$divide`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/) in another [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage, if you must:

```js
db.lineitems.aggregate([
    { "$match": { 
        "shipdate" : { "$gte" : 19940101, "$lt" : 19950101 },
        "partsupp.supplier.nation.name" : { "$regex": '^CANADA' },
        "partsupp.part.name" : { "$regex": '^forest', "$options": 'i' }
    }},
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": null,
        "sum_quantity": { "$sum": "$quantity" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "half_quantity": { "$divide": [ "$sum_quantity", 2 ] } 
    }}
]);
```

Comment: It's perfect. Thank you very much Neil Lunn

Comment: @duknust Don't forget to [Accept Answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), as your account is notably light on accepted answers.